# Trying to understand angularjs service and $http

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, angularjs

I am trying to make `jQuery` `backstretch` to work with AngularJS. I know that there is backstretch fork for AngularJS too, but now that I can't make it work with the `jQuery` one, I would like to understand why. So, let's get started with the code. This is my view

```
<div ng-controller="main" ng-init="images=[];index=0;">
  <div id="bs" ng-swipe-right="nextImage()" ng-swipe-left="prevImage()" style="position: relative;">
    <div id="bslist" style="position: absolute; bottom: 10px; text-align: center;
         left: 0px; right: 0px;" class="bg-stretch">
      <span ng-repeat="image in images">
        <a href="#" ng-class="{'active':isCurrentImageIndex($index)}"
           ng-click="setCurrentImageIndex({{$index}});">{{$index}}</a></li>
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

(I know it's not good to have the styles here, but it is just for the test and I didn't want to embed it into my css)

The idea is that once I have entered the list of images via backstretch to `#bs` I could change them by swiping left or right (which works) or by clicking from a list that the link tags make (which doesn't work). Also, the animated change that `backstretch` does works. The clicking does not work, because when I click, the controller is reran and images in `#bs` are reset. Correspondingly, the index will be 0 always after any click. The backend shuffles the list of images always.

And this is my controller

```
app.controller('main', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
    $http({
      method: 'get',
      url: 'rest/bg'
    }).success(function(data) {
      console.log('Loaded images');
      $scope.images = data.images;
      $scope.index = 0;
      var height = $($($('#bs').parent()).parent()).height();
      $('#bs').css('height', height);
      $('#bs').backstretch($scope.images, {duration: 2000, fade: 700});
      $(window).on("backstretch.after", function(e, instance, index) {
        $scope.$apply(function() {
          console.log('running scope');
          console.log(index);
          $scope.index = index;
        });
      });
    });
    $scope.prevImage = function() {
      $scope.index = $scope.index === 0 ? $scope.images.length - 1 : $scope.index - 1;
      $('#bs').backstretch("show", $scope.index);
    };
    $scope.nextImage = function() {
      $scope.index = $scope.index === ($scope.images.length - 1) ? 0 : $scope.index + 1;
      $('#bs').backstretch("show", $scope.index);
    };
    $scope.isCurrentImageIndex = function(index) {
      return $scope.index === index;
    };
    $scope.setCurrentImageIndex = function(index) {
      $scope.index = index;
      $('#bs').backstretch("show", $scope.index);
    };
  }]);
```

Comment: Try putting your `$http` call in a function, and run it after declaring it, `$scope.load()`

Comment: read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14994391/how-do-i-think-in-angularjs-if-i-have-a-jquery-background

Comment: @MajoB, ok you see where I am coming from... Thanks for the tip. Haven't still adjusted my thinking to AngularJS mood, still hanging too much in jQuery mood.

Comment: @MajoB, I decided to learn how to directive (where one is allowed to use jQuery ;) ) and embed everything there. That worked out quite nicely. I uploaded it to [GitHub](https://github.com/mathCodingClub/angularJS-backStretch-carousel)